# How to Customise PagerTabStrip with stripDrawable and spacing

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a Viewpager and want to set title for the same. I am able to do this. But customizing the same is creating problems for me.

1). I dont want the default strip below the title instead I want my selection bar to be in that place. I know we can change color for the strip but is it possible to give a drawable for the same.

2). I only have 3 pages for ViewPager so I want all 3 titles to be visible at the same time.

3). Can we define the width for the strip below title

Please provide suggestions for the same. Ihave stuck in middle of this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `PagerTabStrip` doesn't offer much customization, [ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) does through and it's open sourced.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly your first question, but try reading this post:

[android: How to add icons/drawables to the PagerTabStrip from the Android Support Lib version 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839031/android-how-to-add-icons-drawables-to-the-pagertabstrip-from-the-android-suppor)

Comment: Please avoid use of sharing just the link, try to summarize the content of the link.