# How to add page title and icon in android FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, fragmentpageradapter

I want to display title with respective icon in  with header page title. like below image, however only able to display title and missing icon.

Here is the my sample code,.

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below) with the page number as its lone argument.

        Log.e("POSITION", "position=" + position);
        Fragment fragment;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
         //Fragment1
        case 1:
         //Fragment2
        case 2:
         //Fragment3
        case 3:
         //Fragment4
        case 4:
         //Fragment5

        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }

    // using both these techniques but could not get icon in title
    /*
     * public int getIconResId(int index) { return ICONS[index % ICONS.length]; }
     */

    public int getPageIconResId(int position) {
        return ICONS[position];
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
        return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
        case 1:
        return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
        case 2:
        return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        case 3:
        return getString(R.string.title_section4).toUpperCase(l);
        case 4:
        return getString(R.string.title_section5).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }

    }
```

and in onCreate:

```
mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
```

Using this xml file for display fragment page adapter in fragment;

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rlv2"
        android:layout_marginTop="-30dp" >

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
            android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"  
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Output image that i need my app.Could you please any idea how to display section page adapter with icon and title.

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I got solution from  **[Stever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839031/android-how-to-add-icons-drawables-to-the-pagertabstrip-from-the-android-suppor)**.

```
Drawable myDrawable;
String title;

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
   switch (position) {
    case 0:
       myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_section1);
       title = getResources().getString(R.string.title_section1);
       break;
    case 1:
       myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_section2);
       title = getResources().getString(R.string.title_section2);
       break;
    case 2:
       myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_section3);
       title = getResources().getString(R.string.title_section3);
       break;
    case 3:
       myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_section4);
       title = getResources().getString(R.string.title_section4);
       break;
    case 4:
       myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_section5);
       title = getResources().getString(R.string.title_section5);
       break;
    default:
      //TODO: handle default selection
       break;
    }

    SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder("   " + title); // space added before text for convenience
    try {
        myDrawable.setBounds(5, 5, myDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), myDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
        ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(myDrawable, DynamicDrawableSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
        sb.setSpan(span, 0, 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        return sb;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
```

Thank you stever.

Comment: getResources() get be called.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/32780701/630833 if not working to due to caps of text.

Comment: how to do this ,i have created selector with 2 images per tab. when i select a tab, my image color will be white with selected state in selector, else image is default black colored. i tried it in above myDrawable. but its not worked.

Answer (score 27):

If you are using the design support library [TabLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html), you can simply call:

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon();
```

Comment: this answer does the job well and saved time. Thanks.

Comment: Call but where? I am using a TabLayout and none of the answers is working, If you call this in bindViewPager then you will get a null reference error. Can you please update your answer within the class of ActionsAdapter as @Dharma did?

Comment: This is the way, HOWEVER, there is some bug in Tablayout/ViewPager in that icons are removed after a fragment refresh. Need to reinsert them each time.

Comment: if getting NullPointer just use ExecutorService with Handler - you are trying `setIcon()` before tabs really drawed / created

Answer (score 1):

for me it worked like this :

```
@Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        SpannableStringBuilder sb;
        ImageSpan span;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.heart_18);
                sb = new SpannableStringBuilder("  Page1"); // space added before text for convenience

                myDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, myDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), myDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
                span = new ImageSpan(myDrawable, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
                sb.setSpan(span, 0, 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

                return sb;
            case 1:
                myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.star_grey_18);
                 sb = new SpannableStringBuilder("  Page2"); // space added before text for convenience

                myDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, myDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), myDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
                span = new ImageSpan(myDrawable, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
                sb.setSpan(span, 0, 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

                return sb;
            case 2:
                myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.star_pink_18);
                sb = new SpannableStringBuilder("  Page3"); // space added before text for convenience

                myDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, myDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), myDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
                span = new ImageSpan(myDrawable, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
                sb.setSpan(span, 0, 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

                return sb;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, Its not working with TabLayout, how can i make this work?

Answer (score 1):

you can use :

```
myTabLayout.getTabAt(index).setIcon(R.drawable.myIcon);
```

Answer (score 0):

Find solve here

Create icon array like this
`private int[] tabIcons = {
            R.drawable.ic_tab_favourite,
            R.drawable.ic_tab_call,
            R.drawable.ic_tab_contacts};`

and setIcon to tabLayout

```
tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
```

`tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
 tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
 tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2])`;

more here

Link1 :https://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Link 2 :http://www.androiddeft.com/tablayout-viewpager-android/