# Use Tab layout in MVVM architecture with the data binding library

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding, android-tablayout, android-databinding

I am developing an app that has a tab layout as the image.

[image]

I’d like to use MVVM architecture with data binding library but I am new with this framework.

I can do this without using MVVM by normally setup tab layout using ViewPager as this sample.

**Normal tab layout without MVVM and data binding:**

activity_main.xml:

```xml
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```java
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
        adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
        adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), "THREE");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

**Tab layout in MVVM:**

When using MVVM with data binding library, we will have to use a view model for the tab layout view.

And I don’t know how to setup tab layout in the XML and also in the view model. How to handle events such as “tap on one tab of the layout” using data binding library

Is there any sample of using Tab layout in MVVM with data binding library?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

MainActivity -

```java
    public class MainActivity extends Activity 
    {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            App.get(this).component().inject(this);
            ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
            binding.setHandler(this);
            binding.setManager(getSupportFragmentManager());
        }
        
        @BindingAdapter({"bind:handler"})
        public static void bindViewPagerAdapter(final ViewPager view, final MainActivity activity)
        {
            final MainActionsAdapter adapter = new MainActionsAdapter(view.getContext(), activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
            view.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        
        @BindingAdapter({"bind:pager"})
        public static void bindViewPagerTabs(final TabLayout view, final ViewPager pagerView)
        {
            view.setupWithViewPager(pagerView, true);
        }
    
    }
```

xml -

```xml
    <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    
        <data>
    
            <import type="android.view.View" />
    
            <variable
                name="handler"
                type="com.ui.main.MainActivity" />
    
            <variable
                name="manager"
                type="android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager" />
        </data>
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
    
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                app:title="@string/app_name"
                app:titleMarginStart="8dp" />
    
            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:pager="@{(pager)}">
            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    
            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:handler="@{handler}" />
    
        </LinearLayout>
    
    </layout>
```

Adapter -

```java
    public class MainSectionsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
    {
        private static final int CONTACTS = 0;
        private static final int CALLS = 1;
        private static final int CHATS = 2;
        
        private static final int[] TABS = new int[]{CONTACTS, CALLS, CHATS};
        
        private Context mContext;
        
        public MainSectionsAdapter(final Context context, final FragmentManager fm)
        {
            super(fm);
            mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
        }
        
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position)
        {
            switch (TABS[position])
            {
                case CONTACTS:
                    return ContactsFragment.newInstance();
                case CALLS:
                    return CallsFragment.newInstance();
                case CHATS:
                    return ChatsFragment.newInstance();
            }
            return null;
        }
        
        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            return TABS.length;
        }
        
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
        {
            switch (TABS[position])
            {
                case CONTACTS:
                    return mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.contacts);
                case CALLS:
                    return mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.calls);
                case CHATS:
                    return mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.chats);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the code behind MainActionsAdapter? Thanks

Comment: added to answer

Comment: I'm trying to add tab layout in a fragment, which means I would need to use getChildFragmentManager. Do you know how could I accomplish this?

Comment: @AntonMakov have you found a way when using Fragments?

Comment: We didn't found a solution on how to use childfragmentmanager wile binding data and eventually we used moved everything to the parent fragment and as the result we didn't need to use childfragmentmanager any more.

Comment: Cannot find the setter for attribute 'app:pager' with parameter type androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager on com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout

Comment: @MiteshVanaliya check your BindingAdapter, if you copied mine, it adds bind:pager to support VIewPager, not "androidx"

Comment: @Dmitrijs I have used this code but no tabs are appearing on the screen only blue bar at the bottom, I have also replaced the fragment names from MainSectionsAdapter with my app fragments but it is still not working.

Comment: @suv This code snippet is from working application, I can't debug your code from a distance, sorry

Comment: @Dmitrijs Its working now, i forgot to apply to change the contentView in MainActivity. Do you know how can i put icons along with texts? I have gone through a lot of SO threads but none seems to be working like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31260384/how-to-add-page-title-and-icon-in-android-fragmentpageradapter/31261273#31261273

Comment: nice answer, what if I need to set the text to textView when tabs clicked how can I achieve this @Dmitrijs

Comment: Good approach ,but it does not work with Viewpager2

Comment: I have already created the BindingAdapter as well and being able to import for app:pager but I am not being able to import  app:handler tag inside viewpager. What might be the issue?

Comment: I wouldnt use Activity or Fragment instances data binding. It causes memory leak.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this is newly introduced recently but with Android Support version 27.1.1, you don't even even need a custom data binding adapter, you can simply use:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tl_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:setupWithViewPager="@{some_fragment_viewpager}"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/v5_grey_55"
                />


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/some_fragment_viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:addOnPageChangeListener="@{vm.pageChangeListener}"
            app:setAdapter="@{vm.pageAdapter}"
            app:setCurrentItem="@{vm.pageChangeListener.currentPosition}"
            />
```

Take note that the `viewPager` variable in `app:setupWithViewPager="@{some_fragment_viewpager}"` points to `android:id="@+id/some_fragment_viewpager"`.
That's how the reference to the ViewPager is done (like magic I know)!

ViewModel

```java
public class SomeViewModel {
  public ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener pageChangeListener;
  public SomeFragmentPagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
  // ...
}
```

FragmentPagerAdapter

```java
public classs SomeFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
  public Boolean currentPosition;
}
```

Comment: could you please share `ViewModel` @ericn

Comment: @ericn, in case that I'm using FragmentPagerAdapter how can I create it in the viewmodel without using fragmentmanager?

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution for `setUpWithViewpager` using `databinding`:

```java
    public class BindingUtil
    {
        @BindingAdapter({ "setUpWithViewpager" })
        public static void setUpWithViewpager(final TabLayout tabLayout, ViewPager viewPager)
        {
            viewPager.addOnAdapterChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnAdapterChangeListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onAdapterChanged(@NonNull ViewPager viewPager, @Nullable PagerAdapter oldAdapter, @Nullable PagerAdapter newAdapter)
                {
                    if (oldAdapter == null && (newAdapter == null || newAdapter.getCount() == 0))
                    {
                        // this function will helpful when 
                        // we don't create viewpager immediately 
                        // when view created (this mean we create
                        // will pager after a period time)
                        return;
                    }
                    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

**xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
     ... 
     app:setUpWithViewpager="@{ viewPager }"
/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
     ...
     android:id="@+id/viewPager"
     app:adapter="@{viewModel.pagerAdapter}"
/>
```

**ViewModel**

```java
    public class MainViewModel extends BaseObservable
    {
        
        @Bindable
        public PagerAdapter getPagerAdapter()
        {
            return adapter;
        }
    
        private void createViewPagerAdapter()
        {
            ...
            notifyPropertyChanged(BR.pagerAdapter);
        }
    }
```

[full demo project here](https://github.com/PhanVanLinh/AndroidBindingCustomTab.git)

Answer (score 0):

as Shown in [Phan Van Linh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47844188/6045800), It's working for me but it shows binding error while we provide `viewPager`'s ID as reference to `tabLayout` in brackets.

I solved this by simply providing the id without brackets and also provide `ViewPager`'s ID in camelCase.