# TabLayout don't get populated with ViewPager at all

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, fragmentpageradapter

I try to populate a `TabLayout` with a `ViewPager` but unfortunately it doesn't get populated.

I followed this tutorial to get in touch: [TabLayout and ViewPager in your Android App](https://android.jlelse.eu/tablayout-and-viewpager-in-your-android-app-738b8840c38a). The tutorial uses the old Support Library v4. My project is based on AndroidX and i want to stay with it. The [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout) of `TabLayout` said that I need to create the `TabLayout` inside the `ViewPager` but that's not working at all. So i created the following **XML layout file**:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/primaryColor"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/primaryTextColor" />

    </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

I **setup the ViewPager** with the following lines to connect `TabLayout` with `ViewPager`:

```java
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
        ...
        // tab layout
        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        MyFragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

My **Adapter** is a `FragmentPagerAdapter`

```java
public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private Context context;

    public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return new MyFragment1();
        } else {
            return new MyFragment2();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return context.getString(R.string.building);
            case 1:
                return context.getString(R.string.buff);
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

One of my `Fragment`s looks like this:

```java
public class MyFragment1 extends Fragment {

    public MyFragment () {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_building, container, false);
    }

}
```

Here is a picture how it looks like:

[Empty ViewPager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzkLr.png)

**Question**

So why is the `TabLayout` not populated at all? I'm working with Android Studio and the Design Manager just shows me an empty `TabLayout` and `ViewPager`. I guess, it would precompile the `TabLayout` but it is just empty...

Please help me because i stuck at this topic. I really want to code it like this to get benefit of swiping tabs and stuff.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution on another thread [Use Tab layout in MVVM architecture with the data binding library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41718377/use-tab-layout-in-mvvm-architecture-with-the-data-binding-library). I'm using Android Data Binding so the `TabLayout` wasn't assigned to the `ViewPager`. So my code was correct but not accordingly to the Data Binding.

Nevertheless, thanks for your posts here!

Comment: This link is not helpful at all in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example from one of my projects .Create and populate `ViewPager`, something like this:

```
 <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/loginViewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/loginTitle">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/loginTabContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabRippleColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabLayoutTheme">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem android:text="first tab" />
        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem android:text="second tab" />

    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
</androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>
```

Then in your activity create a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` to decide what to return in each page. my codes are in kotlin, but java version is the same:

```
    private inner class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {
    override fun getCount(): Int = NUM_PAGES
    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment = when (position) {
        1 -> FirstFragment()
        0 -> SecondFragment()
        else -> FirstFragment()
    }

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
        return when (position) {
            0 -> "First Title"
            1 -> "Second Title"
            else -> "First Title"
        }
    }
}
```

And finally in your Activity:

```
    val pagerAdapter = ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
    loginViewPager.adapter = pagerAdapter
```

Comment: Are you working with Android Studio? Can you tell me whether you see the precompiled design in your Design Manager from the inflated layout?

Comment: @MarcelI. Yes I can see it.

Comment: clean and rebuild the project. also make sure that you used `xmlns:tools` in your main layout.

Answer (score 1):

1. Put your `TabLayout` inside your `ViewPager` like below.

> ```
> <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
>     android:id="@+id/viewPager"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent">
>         <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         app:tabBackground="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
>         app:tabGravity="fill"
>         app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
>         app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
>         app:tabMode="scrollable"
>         app:tabRippleColor="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
>         app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
>         app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white" />
> </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>
> ```

make sure that `android:layout_height` of your `TabLayout` is set to `wrap_content`.

2. When you put your TabLayout inside your ViewPager, you don't need to keep below lines:

   ```
   TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
   tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
   ```
3. Everything else in your code is correct.
4. Also, now that I see your code, `layout_height` of your `TabLayout` is set to `match_parent`, so `TabLayout` is taking whole space in your screen, giving no height to `ViewPager`, also, in your XML, there is no container to hold your `ViewPager` and `TabLayout` (like `LinearLayout`, `FrameLayout` etc).

Comment: I putted the TabLayout inside the ViewPager but it doesn't populate the TabLayout. I debugged the method getItem() from FragmentPagerAdapter and it doesn't get called.

Comment: Okay so it's not giving title to your tabs? Is your ViewPager filled?

Comment: No title and it is not filling ViewPager. Probably, a really simple problem, i think. But i can't figure it out...

Comment: Your code looks correct to me. Did you set your TabLayout height to wrap_content?

Comment: Yes, i did. Looks ok in the Design Manager.

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
```

```
viewPager = (ViewPager)rootView. findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
  ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new FragAllONE(), "ONE");
    adapter.addFragment(new FragAllTWO(), "TWO");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout)rootView. findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
  return mFragmentList.get(position)
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Object object = super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        if (object instanceof Fragment) {
            Fragment fragment = (Fragment) object;
            String tag = fragment.getTag();

        }
        return object;
    }

    public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

}
```