# how to set viewpager with tabLaout in fragment MVVM and DataBinding?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, data-binding, android-mvvm

I want to setup my `viewpager` with `tablelayout` in fragment

fragment:

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

lateinit var bindingFragment: FragmentHomeBinding

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    bindingFragment =
        DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
    return bindingFragment.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    bindingFragment.viewPagerActivity = this
}

companion object {

    @JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter("set_view_pager")
    fun setViewPager(viewPager: ViewPager, context: ActivityMainBinding) {

        val ls2 = arrayListOf<ModelAdapterVpCafeList2>()

        ls2.add(
            ModelAdapterVpCafeList2(
                1,
                "cafename",
                "ali",
                4.2f,
                "adress khione",
                "2",
                1,
                1,
                "https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcds.cern.ch%2Fimages%2FCERN-PHOTO-201802-030-10&psig=AOvVaw1E7wOC9sEGShBjS65AYqsy&ust=1616769050893000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCLC83pvUy-8CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAI",
                0
            )
        )

        ls2.add(
            ModelAdapterVpCafeList2(
                2,
                "cafename2",
                "ali2",
                4.2f,
                "adress khione2",
                "22",
                1,
                1,
                "https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcds.cern.ch%2Fimages%2FCERN-PHOTO-201802-030-10&psig=AOvVaw1E7wOC9sEGShBjS65AYqsy&ust=1616769050893000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCLC83pvUy-8CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAI",
                0
            ),
        )

        ls2.add(
            ModelAdapterVpCafeList2(
                3,
                "cafename3",
                "ali3",
                4.2f,
                "adress khione3",
                "22",
                1,
                1,
                "https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcds.cern.ch%2Fimages%2FCERN-PHOTO-201802-030-10&psig=AOvVaw1E7wOC9sEGShBjS65AYqsy&ust=1616769050893000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCLC83pvUy-8CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAI",
                0
            ),
        )


        val ls: List<ModelAdapterVpCafeList> = arrayListOf(

            ModelAdapterVpCafeList("همه", ls2),
            ModelAdapterVpCafeList("نزدیک من", ls2),
            ModelAdapterVpCafeList("باز", ls2)

        )

        val vpAdapter = AdapterVpCafeList(ls)

        viewPager.adapter = vpAdapter

    }

    @JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter("set_tab_layout")
    fun setTabLayout(tabLayout: TabLayout, viewPager: ViewPager) {
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager, true)
    }

}
```

}

adapter:

```
class AdapterVpCafeList(private val ls: List<ModelAdapterVpCafeList>):  PagerAdapter(){

override fun instantiateItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int): Any {

    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(container.context)
    val binding: LayooutRecyclerviewHomeSearchBinding =  DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.layoout_recyclerview_home_search, container, false)

    binding.cafeList = ls[position]
    container.addView(binding.root)

    return binding.root
}

override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence = ls[position].name

override fun destroyItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int, `object`: Any) = container.removeView(`object` as View)

override fun getCount(): Int = ls.size

override fun isViewFromObject(view: View, `object`: Any): Boolean = view == `object`
```

}

my layout:

```
<data>

    <variable
        name="viewPagerActivity"
        type="ir.arinateam.cafechejori.view.fragments.HomeFragment" />

    <import type="android.view.View"/>
</data>
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            app:set_tab_layout="@{vp}">

        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/vp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            app:set_view_pager="@{viewPagerActivity}"/>
```

but in layout, `app:set_view_pager=@{viewPagerActivity}` I have this error

> Cannot find a setter for  that accepts parameter type 'ir.arinateam.cafechejori.view.fragments.HomeFragment'

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use Tab layout in MVVM architecture with the data binding library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41718377/use-tab-layout-in-mvvm-architecture-with-the-data-binding-library)

Comment: @MohammadTauqir No my question is not related to this question

Comment: What you are trying is wrong. You cannot set fragments on viewpager directly. Use adapter. check the provided link.

Comment: I dont want to set fragment on viewpager. I want to set my viewpager and tablayout in fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by `clean project` and `rebuild project` multiple times.