# TabLayout icons disappear after viewpager refresh

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager, icons

Hello Can someone help me

This is my android source code

```
private int[] tabIcons = {
        R.drawable.ic_tab_gallery,
        R.drawable.ic_tab_facebook,
        R.drawable.ic_tab_instagram,
        R.drawable.ic_tab_album
};

tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);


setupViewPager(viewPager);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
setupTabIcons();
```

And this is how i put icon in TabLayout item

```
private void setupTabIcons() {
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[3]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
    //tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(tabIcons[3]);
}
```

But after refreshing my viewPager all my tabLayout icons disappear.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: how to refresh you viewpager ?

Comment: adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: so your icons are fixed?

Comment: all my tabLayout icons disappear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue and I reassign the icons to tablayout after viewpager refresh.Like

```
for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
        tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(imageResId[i]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setText(textResId[i]);
    }
```

Another approach is to override **getPageTitle** method of Viewpager adapter as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31260384/how-to-add-page-title-and-icon-in-android-fragmentpageradapter).