# ViewPager Image in Fragment Title

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I have maked a ViewPager with 3 Fragments:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),getApplicationContext()));

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }
        });

    }


    private class CustomAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private String fragments [] = {"Fragment 1","Fragment 2", "Fragment 3"};

        public CustomAdapter(FragmentManager supportFragmentManager, Context applicationContext) {
            super(supportFragmentManager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    return new Fragment1();
                case 1:
                    return new Fragment2();
                case 2:
                    return new Fragment3();
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return fragments.length;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return fragments[position];
        }
    }
}
```

I would have instead of the String Title (like Fragment 1,2...) a Image of the drawable Folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not getting from your question that what actually you want to do! but what i assume is you want to set image instead of title of fragment. if yes then it might help you.

you can easily set icon using tabLayout object with getTabAt,setIcon() method.

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon();
```

you can also refer:

[How to add page title and icon in android FragmentPagerAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31260384/how-to-add-page-title-and-icon-in-android-fragmentpageradapter)

P.S if you're question is different free to ask,Thanks.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I want to set image instead of title of fragment :D

Comment: How can I definite the size of the Icon?

Comment: hello, what you mean by definite the size of icon?

Comment: hello, my icons are very little, how can i make them bigger?

Comment: Please increase your icon size and then use it. if you're icons are in mipmap folder move it to drawable folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using tablayout desing:

**tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon();**