# Add icon in PagerTabStrip

Tags: android, android-viewpager, pagertabstrip

I tried to add images along with text in PagerTabStrip but getting error and app is forceclosing. I'm using the instructions as showing in [here](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/implementing-horizontal-view-swiping-using-viewpager-and-fragmentpageradapter-in-android/#comment-970915) for PagerTabStrip with ViewPager. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839031/android-how-to-add-icons-drawables-to-the-pagertabstrip-from-the-android-suppor) post, its shown how to add images but its not working and the code is not complete. So, any help would be much appreciated. I'm using PagerTabStrip becuz I want to have my tab starting from center.

```css
LogCat error

01-11 15:15:47.684: E/AndroidRuntime(7583): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-11 15:15:47.684: E/AndroidRuntime(7583): Process: in.wptrafficanalyzer.viewpagerdemo, PID: 7583
01-11 15:15:47.684: E/AndroidRuntime(7583): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-11 15:15:47.684: E/AndroidRuntime(7583):  at in.wptrafficanalyzer.viewpagerdemo.MyFragmentPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(MyFragmentPagerAdapter.java:45)
01-11 15:15:47.684: E/AndroidRuntime(7583):  at android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip.updateText(PagerTitleStrip.java:276)
01-11 15:15:47.684: E/AndroidRuntime(7583):  at android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip.updateAdapter(PagerTitleStrip.java:321)
01-11 15:15:47.684: E/AndroidRuntime(7583):  at android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip.onAttachedToWindow(PagerTitleStrip.java:252)
01-11 15:15:47.684: E/AndroidRuntime(7583):  at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:12851)
01-11 15:15:47.684: E/AndroidRuntime(7583):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2579)
01-11 15:15:47.684: E/AndroidRuntime(7583):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2586)
01-11 15:15:47.684: E/AndroidRuntime(7583):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2586)
01-11 15:15:47.684: E/AndroidRuntime(7583):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2586)
01-11 15:15:47.684: E/AndroidRuntime(7583):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2586)
01-11 15:15:47.684: E/AndroidRuntime(7583):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2586)
01-11 15:15:47.684: E/AndroidRuntime(7583):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1427)
01-11 15:15:47.684: E/AndroidRuntime(7583):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1192)
01-11 15:15:47.684: E/AndroidRuntime(7583):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6231)
01-11 15:15:47.684: E/AndroidRuntime(7583):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:816)
01-11 15:15:47.684: E/AndroidRuntime(7583):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:619)
01-11 15:15:47.684: E/AndroidRuntime(7583):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:588)
01-11 15:15:47.684: E/AndroidRuntime(7583):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:802)
01-11 15:15:47.684: E/AndroidRuntime(7583):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
01-11 15:15:47.684: E/AndroidRuntime(7583):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
01-11 15:15:47.684: E/AndroidRuntime(7583):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
01-11 15:15:47.684: E/AndroidRuntime(7583):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5388)
01-11 15:15:47.684: E/AndroidRuntime(7583):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-11 15:15:47.684: E/AndroidRuntime(7583):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-11 15:15:47.684: E/AndroidRuntime(7583):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-11 15:15:47.684: E/AndroidRuntime(7583):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:655)
01-11 15:15:47.684: E/AndroidRuntime(7583):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

```html
Adapter

package in.wptrafficanalyzer.viewpagerdemo;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.text.SpannableStringBuilder;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.text.style.ImageSpan;

public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
 
 final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
 Drawable myDrawable;

 /** Constructor of the class */
 public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
  super(fm);
 }

 /** This method will be invoked when a page is requested to create */
 @Override
 public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
  
  MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
  Bundle data = new Bundle();
  data.putInt("current_page", arg0+1);
  myFragment.setArguments(data);
  return myFragment;
 }

 /** Returns the number of pages */
 @Override
 public int getCount() {  
  return PAGE_COUNT;
 }
 
 @Override
 public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {  
  //return "Page #" + ( position + 1 );
  
  SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder(" Page #"+ position); // space added before text for convenience

     myDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, myDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), myDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight()); 
     ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(myDrawable, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE); 
     sb.setSpan(span, 0, 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); 

     return sb;
 }
 
 
 
 
}
```

Comment: Please check the line number 45 of your adapter something is not declare in on-create() and use this directly so got null-pointer. please paste code with line number.

Comment: Line 45 is the second last curly braces. So I think it might be pointing to line: return sb;  ??