# Change color of drawable in PagerTabStrip

Tags: android, android-layout, pagertabstrip

I'm using `PagerTabStrip` with a `ViewPager` to go between the different views of my app and it works well. I use drawables as the `PageTitles` with this method:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12837635/7459644

This also works really well, I do however want to change the colors of the `drawables` when they are selected, is there a way to do this? I use a `onPageListener`, so I do have a callback when a certain page is selected, I simply don't know how to change the color of the given Page-title drawable when that page is selected. For text there is a build-in method, but I can't find any information regarding drawables in the official documentation.

Comment: You know how to color drawables, but do not know how to set them back. right?

Comment: Yes, I can always add a colored drawable to the PagerTabStrip, but after it has been set I'm not sure how I should update the color of the drawable.

Comment: If you have drawable reference, you can `drawable.setColorFilter(0xffff0000, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);` to make it red. Try it.

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks a lot! I'll post the answer as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

As @rupinderjeet stated in the comments, I solved it by keeping the drawable in an array before adding them to the PagerTabStrip. Since I had a reference to the drawables, I simply added a method that changes the colors of the drawables and call it from my onPageListener from my ViewPager. Works like a charm!

```
drawable.setColorFilter(0xffff0000, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```